How can I use preg_match_all to get text not wrapped in html and store in array
I'm working with inconsistent field values like below that I would like to organize into an array.
Field value example:
<ul>
<li>List item 1</li>
<li>List item 2</li>
</ul>

<p style="font-weight: 400;">paragraph</p>
Text not wrapped in html

<strong>Strong text</strong> with no container tag

&nbsp;

I would like to end up with the list items, paragraph, and text on separate lines in an array while keeping the inline html tags:
- List Item 1
- List Item 2
- paragraph
- Text not wrapped in html
- <strong>Strong text</strong> with no container tag

I am currently using preg_match_all to first get the list item text and then the paragraph text.
if ( preg_match_all( '!<li[^>]*>(.*?)</li>!', $field_value, $instruction_matches ) ) {
    foreach ( $instruction_matches[1] as $instruction_match ) {

        $group['instructions'][] = array(
            'text' => '<p>' . trim( $instruction_match ) . '</p>',
        );
    }
}

if ( preg_match_all( '!<p[^>]*>(.*?)</p>!', $field_value, $instruction_matches ) ) {
    foreach ( $instruction_matches[1] as $instruction_match ) {

        $group['instructions'][] = array(
            'text' => '<p>' . trim( $instruction_match ) . '</p>',
        );
    }
}


I'm not sure how to go about getting the other text on separate lines and not wrapped in html tags.

Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML, use DOMDocument.
